# Trouble with scope: External variable not stored

Tags: c, gtk, scope

I'm using focus callbacks to "Delete" the contents of a GtkEntry when someone clicks it (And puts it back if they leave it empty similar to the Title of questions on stack)

However, the variable is emptied when the function ends just like a local variable.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
// A place to store the character
char * store;

// When focussed, save the contents and empty the entry
void
use_key_entry_focus_in_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer user_data){
    if(strcmp(gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(widget)), "")){
        store = (char *) gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(widget));
    }
    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(widget), "");
}
void
othercallback(){
printf("%s",store); // Returns nothing
}
```

Edit with help from answerers I wrote this (No malloc needed):

```
char store[2];
[...]
strcpy(store, (const char *) gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(widget)));
```

Comment: printf is problably printing to your terminal which is line buffered. Can you try `printf("%s\n,store); ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the GTK library, but your problem is almost certainly that you're not taking a copy of the string, you're merely copying its *address*.  You're then replacing the string with `gtk_entry_set_text()`, so the original string disappears.

You will need to do something like:

```
const char *tmp = (char *) gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(widget));
store = malloc(strlen(tmp)+1);
strcpy(store, tmp);
```

And be careful to `free(store)` at some point.

Comment: There's no way to do this without malloc? I'd prefer to just strcpy the string in the first place but that causes a segfault. It worked fine now and I set a constant malloc size (As I know the max length of this particular text entry is 1 char) Would a second malloc on the same variable cause a problme? Should I free the variable before using malloc or would two free()s in a row cause problems too?

Comment: @J V: Oh, right, if it's only ever one character, then you don't need a pointer at all.  Just `char store;` ... `store = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(widget))[0];` ... `printf("%c", store);`

Comment: The text entry returns a character array (The null terminator) Would it be possible to dereference `gtk_entry_get_test()`?

Comment: @J V: Indeed.  The code snippet in my previous comment obtains the first character (see the `[0]`...).

Comment: Ah right! But still, functionality later required it to be a string. Thanks for the help, got it working (See main post)

Comment: @J V: Great!  But be aware that if, for any reason, the string in the GTK thing is *ever* longer than one character, you'll overflow the buffer and corrupt memory somewhere.  You may be better explicitly setting `store[0]` directly, and then setting `store[1] = '\0'` (as opposed to using `strcpy()`).  Alternatively, add an `assert()` on the string-length before you do the copy.